# Grails domain validator not working

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have the following fields in my domain

```
@BindingFormat('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a')
Date advertiseDate

@BindingFormat('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a')
Date closeDate

@BindingFormat('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a')
Date letDate

closeDate validator: { value, contract -> value >= contract.advertiseDate }      
letDate validator: { value, contract -> value >= contract.closeDate }
```

I have the validation errors in the messages.properties file

```
project.Contract.closeDate.validator.error = Close Date cannot be before Advertise Date
project.Contract.letDate.validator.error = Let Date cannot be before Close Date
```

For some reason my validators don't seem to be working.  I am not receiving any errors I am just not receiving my validation errors.

These validations were working at one time when I was using a jquery datepicker with just a `mm/dd/yyyy` format but once I switched to a jquery datetimepicker with a `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a` format it quite working. The only other change I made was to include a format on the gsp like the one below

```
value="${formatDate(format:"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", date:contractInstance?.letDate)}"
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First thing is to confirm whether they're being called at all. That way you will know if it is a problem with the logic in the validators, or something that is stopping the validators form being called at all. I suggest adding a println to the validator to see in the log if it is being called. Something like: `println('In closeDate validator');`

Comment: You should use upper case M for Month: `@BindingFormat('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a')`

Answer (score 0):

You would need below logic in `validator`

```
closeDate validator: { value, contract -> 
    if ( value < contract.advertiseDate ) return ['invalid']
}      
letDate validator: { value, contract -> 
    if ( value < contract.closeDate ) return ['invalid']
}
```

and

```
//messages.properties
project.contract.closeDate.invalid = Close Date cannot be before Advertise Date
project.contract.letDate.invalid = Let Date cannot be before Close Date
```

Returning the key will be used to look up the message for that particular field.

Note the changes to the message keys above which matches to the return key in case of invalid cases. I am assuming `project` is the package name in the message key and the date are bound properly using `@BindingFormat`.